stack 2D contour plot in a 3D graph?
enter image description here
Hi,
I wonder how this graph in paper is created? It looks like a set of 2D contour stacked in a 3D graph. Could anyone guide me how to do it in python? Thanks!
I have tried to stack it, but can not do it in the vertical way.

It has the look of something concocted using IDL which manages to make very cute looking but uninformative graphical presentations of data ideal for showing to senior managers but without conveying any understanding to them. I find the pastel shades of the lines that I can barely see frustrating and the red dots (chicken pox) seriously annoying. YMMV Gnuplot might come close if you persevere. The user interface is rather terse and the learning curve is extremely steep especially for contour plots and 3D. You can get close by drawing the graphs from back to front on VGT axis with opacity 100%.
